# Products Sold by Modifier

Tags: expresso-store, modifiers

If I have an item (for instance, a concert VIP Package, that includes a T-Shirt.. ) that is single SKU with a modifier (T-Shirt Size..), is there any straightforward way to generate a report with a count of the number of each modifier sold?

I tried using a SQL COUNT that joined exp_store_orders to exp_store_order_items but modifiers ia base64 encoded JSON string...

Answer (score 1):

Not really (without looping through the orders in PHP which would be very slow). That's the point of having separate SKUs.

SKU stands for "Stock Keeping Unit", and so by definition if you want to keep track of how many of each item was purchased you should use separate SKUs. In fact Store already provides built in reports to display how many of each SKU you have sold.

The "Single SKU modifier" was really only added in Store 1 to avoid people having to make up lots of SKUs if they didn't need them. But now in v2 SKU names are no longer required fields, so there is not much need for the single SKU modifier any more, you can just create them as regular multi-SKU products, leave the SKU names blank, and get the advantages of separate reporting etc.